# How to push a value in an array in Yul

Tags: solidity, yul

How would you push the `z` value at the end of the for loop in this function ?

```
contract Math {
   uint256[] nums;

    function fpow(
        uint256 x,
        uint256 n,
        uint256 baseUnit
    ) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
        assembly {
            switch x
            case 0 {
                switch n
                case 0 {
                    // 0 ** 0 = 1
                    z := baseUnit
                }
                default {
                    // 0 ** n = 0
                    z := 0
                }
            }
            default {
                switch mod(n, 2)
                case 0 {
                    // If n is even, store baseUnit in z for now.
                    z := baseUnit
                }
                default {
                    // If n is odd, store x in z for now.
                    z := x
                }

                // Shifting right by 1 is like dividing by 2.
                let half := shr(1, baseUnit)

                for {
                    // Shift n right by 1 before looping to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } n {
                    // Shift n right by 1 each iteration to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } {
                    // Revert immediately if x ** 2 would overflow.
                    // Equivalent to iszero(eq(div(xx, x), x)) here.
                    if shr(128, x) {
                        revert(0, 0)
                    }

                    // Store x squared.
                    let xx := mul(x, x)

                    // Round to the nearest number.
                    let xxRound := add(xx, half)

                    // Revert if xx + half overflowed.
                    if lt(xxRound, xx) {
                        revert(0, 0)
                    }

                    // Set x to scaled xxRound.
                    x := div(xxRound, baseUnit)

                    // If n is even:
                    if mod(n, 2) {
                        // Compute z * x.
                        let zx := mul(z, x)

                        // If z * x overflowed:
                        if iszero(eq(div(zx, x), z)) {
                            // Revert if x is non-zero.
                            if iszero(iszero(x)) {
                                revert(0, 0)
                            }
                        }

                        // Round to the nearest number.
                        let zxRound := add(zx, half)

                        // Revert if zx + half overflowed.
                        if lt(zxRound, zx) {
                            revert(0, 0)
                        }

                        // Return properly scaled zxRound.
                        z := div(zxRound, baseUnit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this solution but it's not working

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Math {

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) nums;
    uint256 len = 0;

    function fpowWrite(
        uint256 x,
        uint256 n,
        uint256 baseUnit
    ) public returns (uint256 z) {
        assembly {
                ...
                // Shifting right by 1 is like dividing by 2.
                let half := shr(1, baseUnit)
                let count := 0 // ADDED THIS
                for {
                    // Shift n right by 1 before looping to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } n {
                    // Shift n right by 1 each iteration to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } {
                    ...

                        // Return properly scaled zxRound.
                        z := div(zxRound, baseUnit)

                        // ADDED THIS
                        sstore(count, z)
                        sstore(add(count, 1), add(count, 1))
                        count := add(count, 2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getValues() public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
        uint256[] memory _nums;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            _nums[i] = nums[i];
        }
        return (_nums);
    }

    function getLen() public view returns (uint256) {
        return (len);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for an answer to this as well, to push to a memory array.
Right now I've done this by increasing the size of memory array in yul, and then used solidity to add a value to the last index.

```
// get index to assign value to
uint i = mem_arr.length;

// increase the size of memory array w/ yul
assembly { mstore(mem_arr, add(mload(mem_arr), 1)) }

// assign value
mem_arr[i] = value;
```

Hope this helps